# Optimal control: Maximum area under the curve

Tags: optimization, calculus-of-variations

Suppose we are given two points P = ($2$,$0$), and Q($4$,$0$). I want to find the curve of length 6 connecting P to Q, which encloses the largest area above the horizontal axis. The constraint for this problem is $6 = \int_{2}^{4}\sqrt{1+\dot{y}^2}dx$ and our objective is $J = -\int_{2}^{4}y(x)dx$. At this point I should construct the Hamiltonian but I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: Do you have some extremal theorems that you're expected to use?

Comment: @Al.G. After writing the Hamiltonian, I will show that Pontryagin's minimum principle holds.

Comment: There is no Pontryagin here. No optimal control in there. This is a calculus of variations problem.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1834585/curve-enclosing-the-maximum-area) may help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maximum area under a curve by calculus of variations](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/641854/maximum-area-under-a-curve-by-calculus-of-variations)